# Describe position words

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I were to describe the words *left*, *right*, *front* and *back*, I could say, those are *positions*.

But what if I need to divide those into smaller groups: *left* and *right*, *front* and *back*?

How could I describe those smaller groups?

Comment: As I re-read your question, I'm not sure I understand it.  Are you asking about more specific things like "front left", or for something that includes, say, both "front" *and* "back"?

Comment: I think this question could be much improved by an example showing how you're going to use these words. If I want to be generic, the most obvious choice would be calling them the *left-right group* and the *front-back group*.

Answer (score 1):

It depends in part what you're describing and if there is already a pattern established for such positions, for example, in anatomy, anteromedial combines front and center.

But assuming there is no pattern, I would use the usual adjective suggestions: use the main adjective and modify it with the other.

On a written page, we usually describe something's placement as in the ["upper left corner" rather than "left upper corner"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upper+left+corner%2C+left+upper+corner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupper%20left%20corner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20upper%20corner%3B%2Cc0). For a crowded room, I would use front left, rear left, front right, rear right.

On the other hand, describing pockets, the side usually comes first: [left front pocket, right front pocket](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=front+left+pocket%2Cleft+front+pocket&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfront%20left%20pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20front%20pocket%3B%2Cc0), etc.

So, the context of what position you're trying to refer to matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your smaller groupings are in opposite directions *along an axis*.
"Up" and "down" would also be considered to be *polar opposite directions* in the same way.

In a Cartesian coordinate system, these would be along the x-, y-, and z-axis.

[image: here]